# getting error while submitting (404) in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular8

I am currently working on angular where I have a form in that I have 7 seven fields

I can able to update only email id rest everything will be disable mode.

this is my api url

```
https://18.226.105.193:8092/email/updemail

Body 

    {

        "id":"5feneikekdnfi28ie",
        "emailId":"sdjfk@gmail.com"
     }
```

I am setting like this

service method

```
  updateemail(email:any){
    return this.http.post<any>('/email/updemail',email);
  }
```

and I am calling this in my ts code

```
              constructor(
            private snackbarService: SnackbarService,
            fb: FormBuilder,
            public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<GeneralPopupComponent>,
            private authService: AuthService,
            @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {      
              console.log(this.data);
              this.generalform = new FormGroup({    
                id: new FormControl(this.data.generalForm.id),            
                firstName: new FormControl({value:this.data.generalForm.firstName,disabled:true}),
                middleName: new FormControl({value:this.data.generalForm.middleName,disabled:true}),
                lastName:  new FormControl({value:this.data.generalForm.lastName,disabled:true}),
                dob: new FormControl({value:this.data.generalForm.dob,disabled:true}),
                emailId: new FormControl({value:this.data.generalForm.emailId,disabled:false}),
                phoneNumber: new FormControl({value:this.data.generalForm.phoneNumber,disabled:true})
                
             });
             }

         getValue() {
        return this.generalform.value;
      }

      saveemailID(){
        if (this.generalform.valid) {
          this.authService.updateemail(this.getValue()).subscribe(
            (response) => {
              this.data = response;
              console.log(this.data);
              this.snackbarService.onSuccessAlert(
                'User details saved successfully',
                'Close'
              );
              this.isButtonEnable = false;
            }
            // (error) => this.errorService.handleError(error)
          );
        }
      }
```

when I edit my email id and click save button I am getting error 404

in console I am getting the value for emailid & id also but still not working getting 404

{id: "5f9849fae683696c0a9628b5", emailId: "admin1234@gmail.com"}
emailId: "admin1234@gmail.com"
id: "5f9849fae683696c0a9628b5"

This is the response I am getting

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Error</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <pre>Cannot POST /email/updemail</pre>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: That 404 is coming from your server. What does the server say is going on?

Comment: Unless you're saying the issue is the missing id, in which case you need to fix `this.generalform.value` to include it.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas so that error is from server end right

why i am asking this is when i am seeing request payload only email id is going

Comment: So the issue is why your id isn't in the request, not the 404? You haven't shared any code relating to what `this.generalform` is.

Comment: sorry I am upating the other code

Comment: I have updated the code pleae check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232059/discussion-between-mr-m-and-roddy-of-the-frozen-peas).

Comment: There's no 'id' in generalform in the code you have shared.